# How do I find the static IP of a website?

Tags: website, web, ip

Suppose the web site can be visited through a static IP.  How can I find what it is?

Comment: `ping <website-domain>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `nslookup` this will work in both dos (windows command prompt) and linux terminal enviroments.

Lookup `google.com`

```
nslookup google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Ping isn't always responded to, depending on firewall rules. If it is a domain name, use nslookup to give you the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can click Start menu in Windows and find the Run: and type in 'cmd' or 'cmd.exe' and it will open a DOS terminal.  Then type the following:

```
ping somewebsite.com
```

where somewebsite.com is the site you're referencing.  Another option is visit this site and enter the website address and it will tell you the IP address:

- http://www.selfseo.com/find_ip_address_of_a_website.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: P.S. if you are on a Mac, open the Terminal app and type ping command above.